# Sharepoint Workflow - Prompt user to input approver

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sharepoint-workflow

I am using power automate to create a document approval workflow, and would like the user to be prompted/asked to select the people reviewing the document. The point is that we have many approvers in our team and I do not want to hardcode the e-mail address of one user only.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the trigger as shown below:

[image]